# 400 Bad Request from a REST Service

Tags: ajax, rest, wcf, typescript, service

I am trying to interact with a REST service by passing Json data to the operation contract URL using AJAX, but I keep getting a Bad Request and don't understand why. 
I am cureently coding in Typescript, here is the method to do the Ajax Request:

```
AjaxLogin = (e: JQueryEventObject) : boolean =>
{
   let email = $("#login-email").val(); 
   let pwd = $("#login-pwd").val(); 

        $.ajax({
        cache: false, 
        type: "GET", 
        url: "http://localhost:57522/PizzaService.svc/Login", 
        data: '{"email":"' + email + '", "pwd":"' + pwd + '" }', 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        dataType: "json", 
        success: this.LoginSuccess, 
        error: this.LoginError
    }); 

    e.preventDefault(); 
    return false; 

}
```

The operation contract in the REST service:

```
  [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
        UriTemplate = "/Login")]
        Entities.User LoginUser(string email, string pwd);
```

implemented C# method:

```
 public User LoginUser(string email, string pwd)
    {
        SqlConnection db;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        db = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE customerEmail = @email AND customerPassword = @pwd",db);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", pwd);

        using (db)
        {
            db.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

            if(reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();

                int id = (int)reader["Id"];
                string firstname = reader["customerFirstname"].ToString();
                string lastname = reader["customerLastname"].ToString();
                int houseno = (int)reader["customerHouseno"];
                string postcode = reader["customerPostcode"].ToString();
                string tel = reader["customerTel"].ToString();

                return new User(id, firstname, lastname, houseno, postcode, tel, email, pwd); 
            }
            else
            {
                return null; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks, I really appreciate it.

Comment: try `data: JSON.stringify('{"email":"' + email + '", "pwd":"' + pwd + '" }')`

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately still doesn't work. I honestly thought it would of